# Android Notification invisible Action

Tags: android, android-notifications

community. I'm building an advanced custom notifications in Android app and I've found this method in Android official docs:

```
@RequiresApi(21)
public @NonNull Builder addInvisibleAction(@Nullable Action action) {
    if (action != null) {
        mInvisibleActions.add(action);
    }
    return this;
}
```

The docs describes it as follows:

> Add an invisible action to this notification. Invisible actions are never displayed by the system, but can be retrieved and used by other application listening to system notifications

However I cannot find any example of using this invisible action. So maybe someone here can link me to some code example ? Can I use the invisible action in the same application ?
thanks in advance